# Is the following a subgroup of the given group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G=(\Bbb Z, +)\times (\Bbb Q\setminus \{0\},\cdot)$ and $U=\{(a,b)\in G\mid b=2^a\}$

Can I get some help on how to approach this .

I know that the product of 2 groups is a group.

I know that I have to check: $f,g\in U\implies fg^{-1}\in U$

Comment: [Visit this page for information on how to type in MathJax and $\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: That changes quite a bit.  So, suppose you have $f=(x, x')$ and $g=(y,y')$ both of which are elements of $U$.  Since they are elements of $U$ we know that they are of the form $f=(x,2^x),g=(y,2^y)$.  What is the inverse element of $g=(y,2^y)$?  What is $f\cdot g^{-1}$?  Does $f\cdot g^{-1}$ satisfy the requirements of being an element of $U$?

Comment: I guess inverse of g is (-y, 2^-y) because (y+(-y), 2^y* 2^(-y))=(0,1)

Comment: ggok: Okay, you've found $g^{-1}$.  Can you determine whether $fg^{-1}$ is also in $U$?

Comment: and i guess f*g-1 does satisfy the requirements of being an element U

Comment: Well, there you go, ggok! :-)

Comment: because (x-y, 2^x *2^-y) can be written as (a,2^a) where a= x-y

Comment: Having confirmed that $fg^{-1} \in U$, you've proved $U$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Lol im really sorry. Thank you  for being patient with me . Im just a beginner

Comment: You did great, ggok!  You did all the work!  No need to apologize.  You've nailed it!

Answer (score 0):

A lazy solution: Given $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, there is a unique $b\in\mathbb{Q}$ for which $(a,b)\in U$, namely $b=2^a$. The map $2^\ast:a\mapsto 2^a$ is a morphism, so $U$ is the image of the morphism $(1,2^\ast):\mathbb{Z}\to G$.